# How to display Google maps in PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, google-maps-static-api

I have information in my database and I want export to PDF where there is my google maps data. In the next image, I show, how i want display  my map in a PDF document.

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gvGv.png)

I'm using library TCPDF, But i have a error when export my information with the image maps to PDF:

TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=19.39197217398235,-99.17327449786751&zoom=17&size=400x200&maptype=ROADMAP&markers=color:red%7Clabel:%7C19.39197217398235,-99.17327449786751

I don't know if this a restriction in the use of Static Google Maps API

Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: BD? What's that?

Comment: @tadman It's most likely "base de données" being French for "DataBase". Which are the letters used in that language. Or, that Spanish version ;-)

Comment: @micster about that suggestive edit of yours https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19228140 - please don't use blockquotes for text; that isn't what it's for. I've edited that out.

Comment: Sorry I want to say Data Base (DB).